# How to get the contents of multiple folders having the same structure

Tags: linux, putty

I have an "app" folder in which on I have severals folders.
In each one of those folders, I have a "web" and a "conf" folder.

I would like to know what's inside every one of those folder.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```
find app -type f \( -wholename "*/web/*" -o -wholename "*/config/*" \)
```

This would list all the files inside the `web` and `config` directories.